# nvm not changing node version

Tags: powershell, terminal, nvm

I have some issue with nvm

In first I am running powershell as administrator.

Now I am using node v14.15.0

But I want to change into v10.22.1

for that I am using nvm, here is the pic how I am changing

[image: nvm]

as you see first I am checking version with **node -v** command

From list I see that I have v10.22.1

With command **nvm use 10.22.1** I am changing version and the console says that now using node v10.22.1

After that I am checking with **node -v** that I am now realy using  v10.22.1 and I see that I am still on  v14.15.0

How can I fix that?... I am realy need to use 10.22.1

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just uninstall node and npm from your pc and install nvm. And from nvm you can download node(with npm) and use.

Answer (score 0):

For this, the simple solution is you need to use NVM itself to download node.

So you can try like below,

> Open CMD/Powershell with Administrator rights, and execute below steps.

```
nvm install 12.22.2
```

Now execute `nvm list`

You will find the 12.22.2 as result.

Now execute `nvm use 12.22.2`

It will give message that NVM is now using node version 12.22.2.

That's it.!